# How to use PATH env variable to read /etc/shadow file being regular user

Tags: bash, zsh, shadow

So this was the project that I received and I'm stuck half way.

> In most Linux distributions (Fedora and Ubuntu included), `/bin/sh` is actually a symbolic link to `/bin/bash`. To use zsh, we need to link `/bin/sh` to `/bin/zsh`. The following instructions describe how to change the default shell to zsh:
>
> - login as root
> - `cd /bin`
> - `rm sh`
> - `ln –s zsh sh`
>
> The `system(const char *cmd)` library function can be used to execute a command within a program. The way `system(cmd)` works is to invoke the `/bin/sh` program, and then let the shell program to execute `cmd`. Because of the shell program invoked, calling `system()` within a Set-UID program is extremely dangerous. This is because the actual behavior of the shell program can be affected by environment variables, such as `PATH`; these environment variables are under user’s control. By changing these variables, malicious users can control the behavior of the Set-UID program.
>
> The Set-UID program below is supposed to execute the `/bin/ls` command; however, the programmer only uses the relative path for the ls command, rather than the absolute path:
>
> ```
> int main() 
> {
>     system("ls"); return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> Login as root, write this program into a file named `bad_ls.c`, compile it (using `gcc –o bad_ls bad_ls.c`) and copy the executable as a Set-UID program into `/tmp` with permissions 4755.
>
> Is it a good idea to let regular users execute the `/tmp/bad_ls` program (owned by root) instead of `/bin/ls`? Describe an attack by which a regular user can manipulate the `PATH` environment variable in order to read the `/etc/shadow` file.

I have successfully changed the default shell to zsh, created the executable `bad_ls`, and copied it to `/tmp` with permission ID 4755.

> Describe an attack by which a regular user can manipulate the `PATH` environment variable in order to read the `/etc/shadow` file.

This is where I'm stuck.

After running the `bad_ls` file, I change the `PATH` env Variable to point to the current directory by using the code

```
export PATH =.:$PATH
```

If I run `ls -a /etc/shadow`, all I get is this: `/etc/shadow`

I would be really thankful if you could guide me in this problem.

Comment: You need to think about *why* having a setuid executable that runs `ls` via a `system` call is a bad idea. What is special about `ls`?

Comment: "This is because the actual behavior of the shell program can be affected by environment variables, such as PATH; these environment variables are under user’s control." 
Now I need to know how to read /etc/shadow file by attacking using PATH env variable.  Please help

Comment: Well ... think about how `PATH` is used by the shell when you execute a command such as `ls`. Also have a read of the `NOTES` section of the `system` manual page (`man 3 system`).

Comment: BTW: The first paragraph of the project text should not be taken with a grain (or rather block) of salt. Ubuntu has not been using `bash` as default shell (via symlink to `sh`) for 10 years (!). The last version where thas was the case was 6.06. Instead Ubuntu, as well as Debian and most of their derivatives, use `dash`. Also, you should not - ever - change the default shell (i.e. `/bin/sh`, be it a symlink or even binary) unless you know exactly what that entails. Packages, daemons, etc. may depend on `/bin/sh` behaving in a certain way, where the replacement may do things differently.

Comment: As to the question, another hint may be in order: The name of a program does not necessarily reflect its function.

Comment: @Adaephon The target here is to read `/etc/shadow` while being logged in as normal user (On terminal of course). All I know is that when you use the terminal as a normal user, you run the `/tmp/bad_ls` and use PATH env variable to point to a directory such that when you run the `bad_ls` file, you will be given root privileges and you will then be able to read the `/etc/shadow` file as a normal user. Please reply with a solution ASAP, I've hardly got any time to submit it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this case is that `system("ls")` would run whichever executable named `ls` it finds first in the user's set `PATH`.

This `ls` does not necessarily have to list the contents of a directory. Instead it could be a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat /etc/shadow
```

Let's say you place this script somewhere in a directory below your home directory, for example `/home/datashark/bin` and add this to your `PATH`:

```
PATH="/home/datashark/bin:$PATH"
```

If you now run `ls`, you will not get a directory listing, instead you will receive an error message:

```
cat: /etc/shadow: Permission denied
```

But if you run `bad_ls`, the `system("ls")`-call therein will also look for a executable named `ls` in your `PATH` and find and `/home/datashark/bin/ls` instead of `/bin/ls`. As `bad_ls` runs with elevated root permissions, the script named `ls` will (on certain systems - see below) also run with elevated root permissions and so will the command `cat /etc/shadow`, which will print the contents of `/etc/shadow`.

So it is a bad idea for root to let normal users run `bad_ls` as long as it has SUID privileges, because it would run any program named `ls` that comes first in the user's `PATH`.

---

#### Note:

This does not work on every Linux system. For example, it will not, according to `man 3 system`, work on systems where `/bin/sh` is or links to an (unpatched) `bash` of version 2 or newer (2.0 was released in 1996). `bash` drops privileges on startup. This does not only effect the `ls` script but also the call `system()` before, as `system()` passes the command to `/bin/sh`.

It may work on other distributions that do not use `bash` as `/bin/sh`. Contrary to the the information stated in the project, Ubuntu (like Debian and probably most derivatives of either) uses `dash` and not `bash` as `/bin/sh` and has been doing so since version 6.10 (from 2006! See [this page in the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)). It seems that with recent versions of Ubuntu (at least 16.04) `dash` and therefore `/bin/sh` are patched to automatically drop SUID permissions (Look for "priv" in `man dash`).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Adaephon! Unfortunately, the project was due a day before you posted the answer.

Comment: By the way, how do I create this script?
`#!/bin/sh
cat /etc/shadow`

Comment: @DataShark I am sorry to hear that. Unfortunately I did not  see your comment about the urgency of the matter until a few hours after you posted it. Again, sorry about that. As for the script: just create a file with a text editor and put it in there. Save the file and make it executable with `chmod`.

Comment: Ignore the previous comment. I finally created the script, copied both the files ls and bad_ls to /tmp, set permission 4755 to bad_ls, changed the path to point it to /tmp but when I run the bad_ls file I get this message

Comment: I get the message 
`seed@ubuntu:~$ /tmp/bad_ls
cat: /etc/shadow: Permission denied`

It's actually better than before. Running `bad_ls` previously would only list all the directories.

Comment: It seems that your `/bin/sh` also does drop SUID privileges when starting. I just checked `man dash` on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine and it seems, that Ubuntu is using a patched version of  `dash` which does this by default. I will put the information I fount into the answer. Unfortunately I do not have `sudo`-permissions on that machine, so I cannot really check, if there is a way around that. It seems that Ubuntu (and probably Debian) developers decided to close this loop-hole.

Comment: Hey, you could use what I'm using. It's called SEED Ubuntu provided by Seed labs at Syracuse University. This is what was recommended for us to use to work on the project. They use v12.04
Download the Pre-Built Virtual Machine Image and run it on Virtual Box or VMWare.
[link]http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/lab_env.html[link]
Also could you please confirm if this version of SEED Ubuntu uses dash for `/bin/sh` so that I could inform my professor and have that statement updated from the project. A URL to support the statement would be appreciated.

Comment: [link] (cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/lab_env.html)

Comment: At least the version of *SEEDUbuntu 12.04*, which is marked as "(new)", does indeed use `dash` for `/bin/sh` (I added the relevant link to the last paragraph about dash in my answer). I also tested, whether it is possible to read out `/etc/shadow` as normal user, and it is. Make sure to change ownership of `/tmp/bad_ls` to `root` *before* setting permissions to `4755`, i.e. `chown root:root /tmp/bad_ls; chmod 4755 /tmp/bad_ls`. If it does not belong to `root`, it will not run with elevated permissions. And if you set the permissions before changing ownership, the SUID bit will be removed.

Comment: Thank you for updating with the link in your answer Adaephon. As for your comment regarding change of ownership to _root_ , remember the question in the project states **Login as `root`, write this program into a file named bad_ls.c** So the bad_ls file will automatically be owned by root.

Comment: Yes, I know. It is just that "work as root" is bad advice ( especially when given to beginners). So I ignored and forgot about it. It is better to run only those commands with root privileges, for which it is actually necessary. Anyway, whether compiled by root or later `chown`ed to root, the result should be the same. I was trying to find possible causes, why it may still not work for you.

Comment: Hey @Adaephon I'd really appreciate if you could answer the question I posted at this link. 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/848471/generating-signing-and-verifying-digital-certificates

Comment: Sorry @DataShark, but I am afraid I will not be able to help you with that. I do not really know that much about OpenSSL. But I saw that you already got an answer over at SO, so I hope that helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your concern @Adaephon. Yes, I have found the answer!